# Is there a way to permanently change the associations of NIC cards on a supermicro server?

Tags: linux, networking, port, network-adapter, pxe

There are 4 ports, eth0...eth3, and I want to reassign them so that eth0 is associated with the NIC currently listed as eth2, and eth1 to eth3. Basically swap them. It needs to be permanent and maintain after an OS reinstall. All 4 are part of the motherboard, so no chance to just physically relocate them.

The reason is that I have a PXE server set up that defaults to eth0 for kickstart files and PXE boot menu, but this server uses eth2 or 3 for internet connection. eth0 & 1 (as currently configured) are 10gig ports which we don't use.

Comment: Worth noting, I tried navigating through all the setup/config menus that are available at the splash screen, but couldn't find anything there either.

Comment: What Linux distro are you running?

Comment: it varies, but centos is the most frequent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system uses udev (CentOS does), update the udev rules to persist the changes across reboots. You can using the following process:

**1) Get the MAC address of the NIC. You can do this with:**

```
ifconfig -a | grep -i --color hwaddr
```

**2) Rename the NIC in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`**

It will look something like this:

```
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x1680 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Locate the entry that matches your hardware address from step 1 and change the `NAME` attribute. Make you're changes, save the file and `reboot` to test your changes.

**3) Test changes: Verify your settings are correct with the following:**

```
# ifconfig -a
# ifconfig eth0
# ifconfig -a | less
# ip addr show
```

A more detailed article on the subject can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-rename-ethernet-devices-named-using-udev/). This should work for any distro that uses udev.

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware is configures by udev, you can change the adapter name in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (the exact path might depend on your distro).

The file contains a line like this one:

> #PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
>   SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:e0:6f:01:e4:a5", > ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

Simply change **NAME="eth0"** into **NAME="my-desired-adaptername"**.

Comment: will this change persist if the OS is reinstalled (potentially a different OS such as Ubuntu or RHEL)? Or would it have to be done again.

Comment: That should depend on the installer of that specific OS. However, as the file was written by udev, it might work. I usually wipe the disc clean, before installing an OS, so I cannot tell though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to disable the ones you don't want to use in the bios. All other answers about udev rules will expire when the drives are formatted with a new operating system.

If it's disabled in the bios, Linux won't see them, and it is persistent across reboots and refreshes.